# ArrayList Hashmap Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I am getting `NullPointerException` in the last statement.Please help.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;
for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    HashMap<String,String> contact = new HashMap<String,String>();
    contact.put(TAG_ID, jsonObject.optString("id").toString());
    contact.put(TAG_NAME,jsonObject.optString("name").toString());
    contact.put(TAG_EXT,jsonObject.optString("extension").toString());
    contactList.add(contact);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize contactList 
`

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
 for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
 JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
 HashMap<String,String> contact = new HashMap<String,String>();
 contact.put(TAG_ID, jsonObject.optString("id").toString());
 contact.put(TAG_NAME,jsonObject.optString("name").toString());
 contact.put(TAG_EXT,jsonObject.optString("extension").toString());
 contactList.add(contact);
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

you have not initialize contactList.

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

you have not initialize `contactList`, it should be initialized before use

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList should be iitialized first. Try this,

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
 for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
 JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
 HashMap<String,String> contact = new HashMap<String,String>();
 contact.put(TAG_ID, jsonObject.optString("id").toString());
 contact.put(TAG_NAME,jsonObject.optString("name").toString());
 contact.put(TAG_EXT,jsonObject.optString("extension").toString());
 contactList.add(contact);
}
```